# Reopen votes should be allowed to add comments

Tags: feature-request, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

[**This is the question in the context.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042887/disable-spell-checker-but-keep-suggestions)

Regarding the above question, it was marked as duplicate and was closed. But unfortunately the question marked as its duplicate was an entirely different one, which has absolutely no relation with the question in context. The question is about disabling spell check in Android, while the duplicate is about disabling spell checking in IntelliJ IDEA. One is a programming related question and other is an IDE related question. But unfortunately it was reviewed wrongly and got closed. The question would have been a lot of help to other people who might be facing similar issues, since this kind of a question was never asked before.

So I tried to reopen the question. Now the scenario is, I cannot add a comment along with the reopen vote, and the people reviewing the reopen vote cannot know the reason for which it was voted for reopen. Since they don't see any edits or whatsoever, they will opt to leave it closed. Shouldn't there be an option along with reopen vote to add a comment so that we can let others know why we think that the question should be reopened?

Comment: Just post a comment to the question.  There's no need to tie it to the reopen vote.

Answer (score 3):

This is different to the off-topic questions or flagging posts, as there are a variety of reasons for posts and comments to be unsuitable for the site.

Rather than saying I disagree with the reason for closing because.. it's not unclear or it's not a dupe, and so on, ...
The vote indicates...

*This is an on-topic question for SO*

If there is debate about a question being a dup, the best thing would be to leave a comment. Having facility to leave comments in reopen votes, just adds to the overhead of one uncomplicated system we have.

***If you have real concerns that reviewers are missing something within a post, I'd recommend editing the post to add clarity, to demonstrate the question is not a dup.***

Comment: Just one point: Best is to clarify the question with an edit, not to add one more ephemeral comment.

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree, I edited adding emphasis, but feel free to edit the answer.